# ionic modal - onshow event? (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

is there a way i can listen to an onshow event for my ionic modal?

**My example Code:**

```js
async presentTestModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: TestPage,
      cssClass: 'TestPage'
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

**and on my class something like:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { $ } from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.page.scss'],
})
export class TestPage implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      // bind here
      this.onshow += this.updateCounterUI(3);
  }
  

  updateCounterUI(countdown:number){
      // do something here    
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I have tried using the `ionModalDidPresent` method on my component, however this doesn't execute when the component is shown

Comment: plz help, i tried using ionModalDidPresent but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. In the modal component, when you dismiss the modal, handle the counter there:

```
  async closeModal() {
    await this.modalCtlr.dismiss();
    this.counter + 1; // Put your logic here, and pass it up the chain
    this.navCtlr.navigateRoot(`/main`);
  }
```

Comment: wait, i want the logic to be on the component and not the calling component.

Comment: What about handling it upon dismissal in the modal component? I updated my answer above.

Comment: i'm actualy using the modal as a popup page, which i do some logic and allow the user to do some stuff, then when done, i close it and then return to the previous page, and then i repeat this.

Comment: should i perhaps use something else?

Comment: That's what my implementation does as well. But in the above implementation you have a user event you can make use of in the modal component itself- and it's guaranteed to always be one for one - so your counter will be accurate.

Comment: the countdown will always be at 3, this will then countdown when the modal is displayed, after the countdown finsihes, i start video streaming from app to backend api, but i cant start the countdown since i cant bind to the show event..

Comment: I might just switch this to a page component and handle it like a separate route, then just go to the previous page once i'm done handling my streaming stuff.